# Prevent array linebreaks in CosmosDB documents

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to store an array with 366 integer values in a CosmosDB document.

However, it stores the data with a linebreak and tabs between each element, likes this:

```
[
    0,
    0,
    ...
]
```

Is there a way to store it like the following instead?

```
[0,0,...]
```

I wonder because according to my calculations the first example takes 6kb of storage, and the later takes below 1kb.

Or am I wrong in my thoughts about how it is actually stored, maybe its stored without the linebreaks and tabs? I mean maybe its just in the document viewer user interface I can see the linebreaks and tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mention formatting of results with line breaks, I suppose are you checking it from the [Azure Cosmos DB Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/data-explorer) parses and formats JSON results in readable manner so it is easier to analyze.

Data isn't stored with line breaks, it is software which represents it for you in readable format.

Comment: Thanks! I found a way to check the document size and it seems like it verifies your answer, great :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to writing "indented" JSON with this extra whitespace for readability. It's unlikely that Cosmos DB internally stores this extraneous content for efficiency (I'm not sure), but it could be controlled by the settings applied to the serialization process (of converting your data to JSON).

With .NET at least, neither [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Formatting.htm) or [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.writeindented?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_WriteIndented) indent JSON output by default, so unless you've enabled that option, it wouldn't be stored as such.

To be sure, you could check the `Retrieved Document Size` value of the [query metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-metrics#query-execution-metrics) returned from test queries.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning query metrics, it was new to me. Looking at the metrics it looks like the linebreaks are not stored :)